# Is it possible to auto complete with function braces? c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

When I type some letter of a function name in visual studio, it suggests me to auto complete the name of the method by pressing `Tab`. [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nfT8.png)

After I press `Tab` it auto completes the name of the method without braces, I'm sure you all know how it works.
My question is, is there a way to auto complete the name of the method with braces? instead of auto completing `method_name`, make it be `method_name()`

It will help me a lot because most of the time I just need to execute the method.

Comment: resharper does this for you (and a whole lot more), but it's not a free tool

Comment: You should contact Visual Studio support for this question instead posting it here, I believe.

Comment: You could edit the related snippets. But yes, that means every snippet. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573878/how-to-change-the-a-default-code-snippet-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: @nilsK Thank you, I searched for it and found snippets of shortcuts in visual c# but I have not managed to find what I am looking for. from my understanding its intellisense that auto completes function names and I don't know how to edit it, any help?

Comment: @EliteEdit My bad, i am sorry. You are totally right, snippets and intellisense-magic are different. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987121/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-code-entered-by-intellisense-when-using-auto-code-c), that explains it pretty well. Poke your bosses ribs until you get a resharper licence? ;)
I'm pretty used to it. It's your desired behaviour with resharper, so i got confused. Again, my bad - i am afraid, that wont work with snippets.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT , Thank you for your answer, I have posted a suggestion in the developer community. [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1247540/adding-an-option-to-edit-intellisenses-auto-comple.html] Really appreciate if you upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot get what you want so far.

And VS does not such **Intellisense** function by default.

**As a suggestion**,

**1)** just as `NDJ` said, [Resharper vs extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has the option that automatically add brackets to methods when auto-completing.

**And Resharper** is free for 30 days if you are a new user.

**2)** Or before you click **Enter** to complete automatic filling from the Intellisense suggestion window, press the key combination `Shift + (` and it will automatically add `()` with the method.

[image]

===============================================

**Besides**, if the two suggestions do not meet your requirements, you should [suggest your idea to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

**And** when you finishing the ticket, you can share the link here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it.

With all of these, I think it will get more attention from **Microsoft** to help us deal with it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, @Perry Qian-MSFT said that now its not quite possible to do it, and suggested me to post this idea to the team.

[Here is a link to it,](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1247540/adding-an-option-to-edit-intellisenses-auto-comple.html) Make sure you all upvote it if you want this idea to get attention from Microsoft, I will really appreciate it.