# visual studio intellisense for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

I am using visual studio and In the following c++ code

```
using namespace std;

void f() {

}

int main()
{
    // using ctrl + space
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When I use Intellisense suggestions in main function it does suggest **f** function but when I click on it or press tab it just writes f not f().
Is there anyway to correct this and not to add () myself after all function calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a well-known problem that [I have handled it before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676988/is-it-possible-to-auto-complete-with-function-braces-c-sharp-visual-studio/64694800#64694800).

For VS, actually, it could not be done automatically now and VS does not have this Intellisense feature by default.

**As a suggestion**, before you click **Enter** to complete automatic filling from the Intellisense suggestion window, press the key combination **Shift** + **(** and it will automatically add `()` with the method.

**Or** just Use [Resharper Extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and this extension has the feature for automatically adding brackets to methods.

**Besides**, [this DC ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/adding-an-option-to-edit-intellisenses-auto-comple/1247540) has raised this idea to the Team. You could vote it and more votes will help the Team pay more attention to this and add this feature to VS IDE as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Resharper is the extension that does just that
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/